# Is there a screenshot taking app like gyazo on ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04

Guys i want to find a screenshot taking app for ubuntu which could take screen shots and creates its URL which could be further used in sending some like there is a app for windows which is called gyazo which can do the same?

Comment: There are several screenshot utilities for Linux . What features exactly you're looking for ? I didn't understand. Also, what about  `gyazo` ? what exactly so special about it ?

Answer (score 3):

You can install gyazo on Ubuntu. Open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/gyazo/gyazo-for-linux/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get install gyazo
```

[More info.](https://github.com/gyazo/Gyazo-for-Linux)

Comment: While line one finishes OK, the second line says gyazo is not found.

Comment: @Zon Try running:`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gyazo` and please post any more errors. Thanks!

Comment: Tried. The same, unfortunately.

Comment: Installed Flameshot on Mint 19 without problems instead.

Comment: @Zon Okay, problems for linux mint are off topic on askubuntu. If you go to the gyazo github page you will see many bugs reported for this problem installing on linux mint systems. Questions for linux mint belong on https://unix.stackexchange.com and you can even search for linux mint questions at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux-mint

Comment: Why off topic - isn't Mint Ubuntu based?

Comment: @Zon Mint is not an official ubuntu flavor. See here: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic "Questions that you should avoid"

Answer (score 0):

You can install and use Shutter by typing:

```
sudo apt install shutter
```

also you can take screen shots by pressing **PrtSc** key in keyboad.
And also **Kazam** is another helpful app.

```
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

Comment: How about upload and linking?